# Django + MySQL - Unknown encoding: utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, django

MySQL 5.5.35
Django 1.6.1

In order to support emoticons in the DB, I have configured in my django settings:

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}
```

On MySQL connection, I get this error:
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8mb4

How should I configure Django/MySQL in order to support utf8mb4?

Comment: You may want to verify the MySQL version in use.

Answer (score 18):

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392#comment:10

> As a workaround, you can make python understand 'utf8mb4' as an alias
>   for 'utf8':
>
> ```
> import codecs
> codecs.register(lambda name: codecs.lookup('utf8') if name == 'utf8mb4' else None)
> ```

Comment: @ChrisSH - I don't remember where I put it...  It needs to run once and probably before it makes the DB connection.  Maybe in the `__init__.py` or in `settings.py`?

Comment: this is also worked for sqlalchemy to connect mysql database.

Comment: @GünayGültekin - I think the [issue is specific to the db adapter used with sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection) and not sqlalchemy itself.  Which adapter are you using that this works with?

Comment: @GünayGültekin - have you tried passing the [`charset` arg as shown in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection)?  It seems like your adapter should support `utf8mb4` out-of-the-box (according to the docs).

Answer (score 11):

If you really need utf8mb4, 
follow the steps in https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4, and 
make sure your python package "MySQL-python" version is >= 1.2.5 !

Answer (score 0):

Fast and easy way.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='username',
                                   password='mypass',
                                    host='localhost',
                                     database='mydb',
                                       use_pure=True,
                                      charset='utf8'
                                      )
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. An explanation (with proper references) will make this answer upvote worthy :)

Answer (score -1):

This worked in my case (MySQL 5.7 + Django 3.1):

**Configure Django:**

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'OPTIONS': {
 'charset': 'utf8mb4' 
}
```

**Configure MySQL database**

1. make sure all db tables are using **InnoDB** storage engine (this is important; the next step will probably fail if you skip it)
2. change the Collation for all your tables to **utf8mb4_general_ci**