# MySQLdb and _mysql versions ncompatible: how to upgrade _mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm running MySQLdb v1.2.3 and getting the following error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8mb4
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517358/django-mysql-unknown-encoding-utf8mb4) suggests updating MySQLdb to version 1.2.5. I updated and am now getting this error:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

I'm not sure how to go about updating `_mysql` or how this will change my setup. Is this just a python module or is it connected in some way to my MySQL server?

**EDIT:** I've tried running the following three methods:

```
sudo pip uninstall mysql-python
sudo pip install mysql-python

sudo pip uninstall mysql-python
sudo pip install mysql-python==1.2.5

sudo pip install mysql-python --upgrade
```

When uninstalling I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql_exceptions.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql_exceptions.pyc
Proceed (y/n)? y
Successfully uninstalled MySQL-python-1.2.3
```

After that I am unable to import either `MySQLdb` or `_mysql` but reinstalling always gives me `_mysql` version 1.2.3.

Comment: looks similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27138539/2253302

Comment: @alexander.polomodov looks similar, but opposite question. That question updates MySQLdb to match `_mysql`, I'm trying to update `_mysql` to match `MySQLdb` (because I need a specific version of `MySQLdb`). There are a bunch of similar questions to the one you posted, but none address the reverse. Also note that some of the comments in that link also ask for help with the reverse.

Comment: So, the question boils down to "How do I upgrade MySQLdb?"

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? The docs explain what _mysql is mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysql , the last relaese is a couple of years old. You should  check out the github page https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1. Also https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ might be of interest

Comment: What plateform are you running (Debian/red-hat linux?) This is a system dependency problem.

Comment: MySQL version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 2):

According to the [user manual](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id3):

> If you want to write applications which are portable across databases, use MySQLdb, and avoid using this module directly. _mysql provides an interface which mostly implements the MySQL C API. For more information, see the MySQL documentation. The documentation for this module is intentionally weak because you probably should use the higher-level MySQLdb module.

Basically, _mysql is an object-oriented wrapper for the MySQL C API.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536103/how-can-i-upgrade-specific-packages-using-pip-and-a-requirements-file) explains how to use pip to upgrade one module, a module with all its dependencies, or any combination thereof. I think that, given the statement, MySQLdb does not have a dependency on _mysql, and they were not upgraded together. Please visit the link shared.

**EDIT:** After some digging, I found that Ubuntu does not support MySQL nicely, and just pip doesn't work.

So I went to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29150749/4900327) and did:

`apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

before doing

`sudo pip install MySQL-python`

This worked nicely for me. For you, I think you may need to upgrade or even apt-get remove and then reinstall the above two Ubuntu modules `python-dev` and  `libmysqlclient-dev`.

For me, it's working now when installing for the first time; go to a terminal and enter the python interpreter, then type:

```
import MySQLdb
MySQLdb.__version__    #I got '1.2.5'
import _mysql
_mysql.__version__    #Again, I got '1.2.5'
```

Comment: I've tried running the `--upgrade` and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Always MySQLdb 1.2.5 and _mysql 1.2.3. See edit in original post.

Comment: Okay I think I've got the solution. Please see my answer.

Comment: This is what I am worried about, going down a long line of dependencies. I'm hesitant to reinstall both `python-dev` and `libmysqlclient-dev`. Uninstalling `MySQLdb` uninstalls `_mysql`, similarly, installing `MySQLdb` installs `_mysql`, which makes me think it is independent of the two packages you mentioned. I'm able to install any version of `MySQLdb` but for some reason I always get v1.2.3 of `_mysql`.

Comment: Figured out the issue, see my above edits. Thanks for trying to help, I'll give you the bounty for the effort.

Comment: Ah I see. I was going to make the argument that upgrading is best for dependencies, more stable and less future headaches yadayadayada, but glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `_mysql` was installed in two different places on the server.

I uninstalled/installed, like this:

```bash
sudo pip uninstall mysql-python
sudo pip install mysql-python

sudo pip uninstall mysql-python
sudo pip install mysql-python==1.2.5

sudo pip install mysql-python --upgrade
```

I then upgraded `_mysql` to v1.2.5 but whenever I then imported `MySQLdb`, precedence was given to the other version of `_mysql` which was not being touched by `pip`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35853790/3) to the question [MySQLdb and _mysql versions ncompatible: how to upgrade _mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853790/mysqldb-and-mysql-versions-ncompatible-how-to-upgrade-mysql) by the OP [Sal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3891715/sal) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>